# CSS Grid item overlap

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like to use CSS grid to lay out some items that, when they're in the same column and overlapping, give each other some space. Here's an image to illustrate what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="yoga"></div>
 <div id="samurai"></div>
 <div id="lunch"></div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;

  display: grid;
}

#yoga {
  background-color: red;

  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 7;
}

#samurai {
  background-color: green;

  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

#lunch {
  background-color: blue;

  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

And a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jraynolds/pen/qBBPXYB?editors=1100) that fails to achieve it is here.
Is what I'm trying to do possible with CSS Grid? The only way I can think of doing it is by splitting columns into further columns--which becomes prohibitive if I have too many items sharing a single column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you've got the wrong start column for yoga and should use grid-template-columns: n the container to set the widths and column gap for spacing.  use at least 1 fraction and not a % to make the column width stay within the space provided.

```
#container {
grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr 1fr
grid-column-gap: 10px

}
#yoga {
grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

Comment: Although this would be a great way to achieve the image that I posted, it doesn't answer the question that I have: how can I achieve same-column items that split the column with each other without making an arbitrarily large number of columns?

Comment: I really do not understand what it is you want from the words you are using. I followed the diagram and the existing code. Are you asking that when you put DIV in to the area marked 2 that it will split by the number of DIV's that are contained within?

Comment: Correct. Is this something CSS grid is capable of and if not, do you know of something that is?

Comment: make two DIV's inside the container. and make both of those also a GRID, and set the to grid-template-colums: auto; You will then have to use some CSS selector to work out the 2nd or nth DIV to make the row start happen

Comment: I think I understand. However, if I wanted 5 overlapping items in one column, I believe I would then need 5 separate container divs inside the column--thus leading to the problem of ever-increasing containers.

Comment: yes, that is the way the HTML and CSS works.  you need to use tag's to hold things.